# What is a modular degree course?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I looked it up, but I didn't understand much. Here's a part of Google search results:

> The University’s courses are
>   modular in structure. A
>   module is a component of a
>   course or undergraduate
>   Honours subject with its
>   own approved aims and
>   outcomes and assessment
>   methods.
>   Each module is taught and
>   assessed within a semester
>   or across the whole year
>   (often referred to as ‘long-
>   thin’)

Can you explain it in simpler terms and with an example?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a UK exclusive thing. From the 2 schools I looked at it seemed to me that "modules" are more or less just "classes".

So instead of taking classes each term they take modules. It seems to me that it's just overcomplicating things, but maybe I'm missing something. Hopefully someone who studies in the UK can offer a more solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't take a bunch of exams at the end of semester and you don't study everything at the same time. You study one thing for a month or so, write an exam and you're done with it, moving on to the next. This means that at the end of the semster you only have one exam from the last module. I like this system, helps to concentrate on one thing at a time.